# ByteBuffer allocate direct example

Tags: java, jsp, byte, buffer, bytebuffer

I am writing a Java program for fun which stores sensitive information from users.

For this reason I want to ensure that the garbage collection does not touch it, so that in the future when I am finished I can wipe it from memory.

So far I have this line of code creating 2048 bytes which is more than enough to store any user's passwords.

My question is how do I store a String such as "secret123", and after delete it? This is a very basic question I know but I could not see it in the documentation. I am probably making this more difficult than it is in my head, but better safe than sorry.

```
ByteBuffer pass = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2048);
```

I am aware of other risks such as swap page files, the computer being coldboot attacked etc...

Thanks!

EDIT:
In response to first answer - I mean to fill memory with '0' characters afterwards, not to free it.

Comment: They're bytes, not characters. But haven't I answered your question?

Comment: @erickson  pass.put((byte) 0); gives me an error saying identifier is expected.

Comment: @erickson When I type "pass." I do not get a list of things, for example normally I would have .toString() etc... but I see none of that. Identifier expected, illegal start of type, then it says identifier expected again.

Comment: You'd have to provide more context. It sounds like you aren't following basic syntax rules.

Comment: @erickson pass.clear(); causes an error like that method does not exist. Same for pass.put etc...

Comment: Provide an [MVCE.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @erickson http://pastebin.com/RxDbpnGw

Comment: All Java statements have to be in a method, and all methods have to be in a type. That "method" might be a class or instance initializer, constructor, etc., but you can't just start writing code at the top level of a compilation unit.

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad" because we can't really start from zero and teach you Java in a single question.

Comment: @erickson Excuse me but I know Java. Perhaps in the pastebin you wanted me to include the class etc... which has caused you to think this way? I just showed you imports I used, and those two lines of code.

Comment: Why would you skip the lines that matter (class and method declarations), but include those that don't (unused imports)? Review "M" and "C" in MVCE. When you are having trouble writing a method invocation, ignorance of Java is a reasonable guess.

Comment: @erickson I got it working, made a dumb mistake my bad.

Comment: Great! I wasn't trying to give you a hard time, but I knew there had to be a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't explicitly free the allocated memory, but you can clear the buffer and then write zeros (or random bytes) to the buffer when you are done. This will destroy any data that was previously stored in the buffer, reducing the window of attack.

```
pass.clear();
while (pass.hasRemaining())
  pass.put((byte) 0);
```

Comment: If you are willing to delve into reflections and sun/oracle specific code, you can free the memory. but explicitly setting to 0 is best solution from security perspective

Comment: Right, it's called `Unsafe` for a reason, but there is work underway to standardize and support some of these function. I'm not sure if buffer management will be included.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @erickson's approach, if you allocate the byte array yourself and create the `ByteBuffer` by wrapping, then you can clear the array with a call to `Arrays.fill()`.

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[2048];
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
//... do your thing here
Arrays.fill(byteArray, (byte)0);
```

As long as you maintain a reference to either the `byteArray` or the `ByteBuffer`, garbage collection won't touch the byte array. You can also get the array back later by calling `ByteBuffer.array()` and then zeroing it out. (NB: You are not guaranteed an actual array if you try this with a `ByteBuffer` created by `allocateDirect()`.)

Comment: calling `allocateDirect` makes it very unlikely that there will be an accessible backing `byte[]`

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I was suggesting it as an alternative, if direct allocation was not actually a requirement.

Comment: @dcsohl I don't think this is correct, as it uses the garbage collector, compared to allocate direct which is handled by OS so you're sure it will be securely wiped?

Comment: The call to `Arrays.fill()` will wipe out the byte array before it's garbage collected. That's my whole point: if you are using direct allocation purely to be more secure, it's not necessary. If you are using it for other reasons, then ignore me and carry on.